# Transfer wallet coins without syncing

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, wallet

I have not synced my wallet in 2 years and I would like to cash out my coins without syncing for 2 weeks or more. I do have wallet backup. Is it possible to use backup wallet somewhere online so my coins are available instantly?

Comment: Still not fully clear as I understand I will need passphrase. I was hoping to import my wallet.dat file into online service, but I guess this is not possible.